# can not see and active a projects under subpath on gitlab

Tags: drone.io

I'm trying to POC drone.io with my k8s & gitlab.

so my gitlab has subpath like "gitlab.com/foo/bar/myproject" but in drone-UI it has seen only the projects under foo path.
and I have a lot of projects in the subpath. so I cannot transfers it all.

did I missed some configuration or it's not implemented yet

Comment: Drone does not support subprojects.

Comment: is that are in the plan or roadmap?

or can I manual add projects to drone?

Comment: We face same problem too.